# php смена кодировки строки

Tags: php

После преобразование строки с одной кодировки в другую, через функцию iconv, в некоторых местах появляются непонятные символы в виде кдваратика со знаком вопроса. Как можно от них избавиться?

Вот пример: "Химчистка автомобиля�?нформационный портал Ярославля и области�?"

код:

```
$rss = ob_get_contents(); 
$rss = mb_convert_encoding($rss, "windows-1251", mb_detect_encoding($rss));
```

Comment: Мало информации, могу предположить что вы конвертируете из UTF-8 в windows-1251 - это так? Строка которую вы конвертируете уверены что она верная? Настройки mbstring? mb_convert_encoding так же преобразовывает?

Comment: Приведите фрагмент кода, в котором происходит конвертация

Comment: $rss = ob_get_contents();
 $rss = mb_convert_encoding($rss, "windows-1251", mb_detect_encoding($rss));

mb_detect_encoding - возвоащает utf-8

Comment: Ой.... Зачем вам в кодировку windows-1251 её как минимум linux и android не понимают... Был даже этап когда все переводили на оборот из cp-1251 в utf-8...